# Call of Duty: Black Ops vs Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2 - CoDPoints vs Unlocking

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

From what I understand, all unlocks are obtained in Black Ops through purchasing with CoD Points, which are obtained from leveling. In Modern Warfare 2, unlocks are available by getting certain amounts of kills with certain weapons. Which is a better system for a completionist? Will the CoD Points system restrict me from getting every weapon, perk, etc. in the game? Does prestige reset both your weapons and CoD Points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a completionist, I would say the better system is CoD points because you can just play the games how you want without having to adapt to style of play required for the gun, attachment or perk.

The only restriction for CoD points system is completing the specific challenges for unlock the Pro perks and leveling up to unlock a particular weapon.

Yes, prestige resets both your weapons and points.